# Short-lived memoization in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, memoization

In an object-oriented language when I need to cache/memoize the results of a function for a known life-time I'll generally follow this pattern:

1. Create a new class
2. Add to the class a data member and a method for each function result I want to cache
3. Implement the method to first check to see if the result has been stored in the data member. If so, return that value; else call the function (with the appropriate arguments) and store the returned result in the data member.
4. Objects of this class will be initialized with values that are needed for the various function calls.

This object-based approach is very similar to the function-based memoization pattern described here: http://www.bardiak.com/2012/01/javascript-memoization-pattern.html

The main benefit of this approach is that the results are kept around only for the life time of the cache object. A common use case is in the processing of a list of work items. For each work item one creates the cache object for that item, processes the work item with that cache object then discards the work item and cache object before proceeding to the next work item.

What are good ways to implement short-lived memoization in Haskell? And does the answer depend on if the functions to be cached are pure or involve IO?

Just to reiterate - it would be nice to see solutions for functions which involve IO.

Comment: As Louis Wasserman said in his comment— the standard Haskell lazy evaluation mechanism for values does pretty much _exactly_ what you describe here: a value is first defined by a thunk, i.e. a function that must be called to get the desired value. When that value is requested, the thunk is evaluated and the result stored. Once nothing owns the reference to the value anymore, it will be wiped by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's use Luke Palmer's memoization library: [Data.MemoCombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-memocombinators/0.4.3/doc/html/Data-MemoCombinators.html)

```
import qualified Data.MemoCombinators as Memo
import Data.Function (fix) -- we'll need this too
```

I'm going to define things slightly different from how his library does, but it's basically the same (and furthermore, compatible). A "memoizable" thing takes itself as input, and produces the "real" thing.

```
type Memoizable a = a -> a
```

A "memoizer" takes a function and produces the memoized version of it.

```
type Memoizer a b = (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

Let's write a little function to put these two things together. Given a `Memoizable` function and a `Memoizer`, we want the resultant memoized function.

```
runMemo :: Memoizer a b -> Memoizable (a -> b) -> a -> b
runMemo memo f = fix (f . memo)
```

This is a little magic using the fixpoint combinator (`fix`). Never mind that; you can google it if you are interested.

So let's write a `Memoizable` version of the classic fib example:

```
fib :: Memoizable (Integer -> Integer)
fib self = go
  where go 0 = 1
        go 1 = 1
        go n = self (n-1) + self (n-2)
```

Using a `self` convention makes the code straightforward. Remember, `self` is what we expect to be the memoized version of this very function, so recursive calls should be on `self`. Now fire up ghci.

```
ghci> let fib' = runMemo Memo.integral fib
ghci> fib' 10000
WALL OF NUMBERS CRANKED OUT RIDICULOUSLY FAST
```

Now, the cool thing about `runMemo` is you can create more than one freshly memoized version of the same function, and they will *not* share memory banks. That means that I can write a function that locally creates and uses `fib'`, but then as soon as `fib'` falls out of scope (or earlier, depending on the intelligence of the compiler), **it can be garbage collected**. *It doesn't have to be memoized at the top level*. This may or may not play nicely with memoization techniques that rely on `unsafePerformIO`. `Data.MemoCombinators` uses a pure, lazy Trie, which fits perfectly with `runMemo`. Rather than creating an object which essentially becomes a memoization manager, you can simply create memoized functions on demand. The catch is that if your function is recursive, it must be written as `Memoizable`. The good news is you can plug in any `Memoizer` that you wish. You could even use:

```
noMemo :: Memoizer a b
noMemo f = f

ghci> let fib' = runMemo noMemo fib
ghci> fib' 30 -- wait a while; it's computing stupidly
1346269
```

Comment: I've actually taken this code and turned it into a cute little package. See [Hackage > package > runmemo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/runmemo)

Comment: This is very helpful, but can you use this method for functions which perform IO, For example, reading the contents of a file? Many times you don't care _when_ you read the file, but you don't want to read the file unless you need to and you don't want to read the file multiple times.

Comment: user5402: Perhaps. Do you want the file handle closed as soon as possible? Do you want the file to be read in its entirety into memory all at once, or only as much as needed? If the answer to both of these questions is "no", then you can simply use `hGetContents`. If the answer is "yes", then you should look into using the `conduit` package. You might be able to build a `Memoizer () (IO String)`, I'm not sure. But remember, `IO String` is *not* a function: it has no input, so by itself cannot be memoized.

Comment: @user5402 Again, I've made a cute little package for "memoizing" IO actions. Nothing groundbreaking. But since an IO action is *not* a function, it is incompatible (though comparable) with the `runMemo` technique. See [Hackage > package > io-memoize](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-memoize)

Answer (score 4):

Lazy-Haskell programming is, in a way, the memoization paradigm taken to a extreme. Also, whatever you do in an imperative language is possible in Haskell, using either IO monad, the ST monad, monad transformers, arrows, or you name what.

The only problem is that these abstraction devices are much more complicated than the imperative equivalent that you mentioned, and they need a pretty deep mind-rewiring.

Comment: If you just want a pure value computed from another pure value, then just plain laziness will do the "caching" for you already.

Comment: Careful. Some people may read that and wonder why the naive Fibonacci number algorithm takes so long.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the above answers are both more complex than necessary, although they might be more portable than what I'm about to describe.

As I understand it, there is a rule in `ghc` that each value is computed exactly once when it's enclosing lambda expression is entered.  You may thus create exactly your short lived memoization object as follows.

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
indexerVector :: (t -> Int) -> V.Vector t -> Int -> [t]
indexerVector idx vec = \e -> tbl ! e
  where m = maximum $ map idx $ V.toList vec
        tbl = V.accumulate (flip (:)) (V.replicate m []) 
                 (V.map (\v -> (idx v, v)) vec)
```

What does this do?  It groups all the elements in the `Data.Vector t` passed as it's second argument `vec` according to integer computed by it's first argument `idx`, retaining their grouping as a `Data.Vector [t]`.  It returns a function of type `Int -> [t]` which looks up this grouping by this pre-computed index value.

Our compiler `ghc` has promised that `tbl` shall only be thunked once when we invoke `indexerVector`.  We may therefore assign the lambda expression `\e -> tbl ! e` returned by `indexVector` to another value, which we may use repeatedly without fear that `tbl` ever gets recomputed.  You may verify this by inserting a `trace` on `tbl`.

In short, your caching object is exactly this lambda expression.

I've found that almost anything you can accomplish with a short term object can be better accomplished by returning a lambda expression like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use very same pattern in haskell too. Lazy evaluation will take care of checking whether value is evaluated already. It has been mentioned mupltiple times already but code example could be useful. In example below `memoedValue` will calculated only once when it is demanded.

```
data Memoed = Memoed
  { value       :: Int
  , memoedValue :: Int
  }

memo :: Int -> Memoed
memo i = Memoed
  { value       = i
  , memoedValue = expensiveComputation i
  }
```

Even better you can memoize values which depend on other memoized values. You shoud avoid dependecy loops. They can lead to nontermination

```
data Memoed = Memoed
  { value        :: Int
  , memoedValue1 :: Int
  , memoedValue2 :: Int
  }

memo :: Int -> Memoed
memo i = r
  where
  r = Memoed
    { value        = i
    , memoedValue1 = expensiveComputation i
    , memoedValue2 = anotherComputation (memoedValue1 r)
    }
```